# Secure a url that has a cname record

Tags: ssl, dns, cname

I have a site that has subdomains for each user and a wildcard SSL Cert

https://user1.mysite.com

https://user2.mysite.com

The question is can someone set a cname record such as user1.theirsite.com -> user1.mysite.com and have it still use https?

Will it work if they install a SSL Cert on their server to secure the connection?

Thanks

Comment: If they use a CNAME on their server to point to yours, they'll never be contacted for an SSL certificate in the first place... right? What are you specifically worried about?

Comment: Users will see that the Connection is Untrusted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way for this to work is if they arrange *with you* to have your SSL certificate include their "alias" as a `Subject Alternate Name` extension in *your* X.509 certificate.

This is the approach used by some CDNs when they host `https` sites for clients - they put all of the known site names that are hosted on one server in one large SSL certificate, and then the clients use CNAMEs to point their domain at the right CDN server.

Comment: Not a bad option indeed of course. It carries the same responsibility as being given a certificate + private key (and can make the application procedure more complex), but can work without SNI.

Comment: This could work.  The options I see on godaddy have a Multiple Domains SSL or an Unlimited Subdomain SSL.  Is there a combo one or would I use two?

Comment: Cannot that one large SSL certificate become too large? What if there are 1000 clients?

Answer (score 12):

The host name and certificate verification (and in fact, checking that SSL is used at all) are solely the responsibility of the client.

The host name verification will be done by the client, as specified in [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1), based on the host name they request in their URL. Whether the host name DNS resolution is based on a CNAME entry or anything else is irrelevant.

If users are typing `https://user1.theirsite.com/` in their browser, the certificate on the target site should be valid for `user1.theirsite.com`.

If they have their own server for `user1.theirsite.com`, different to `user1.mysite.com`, a DNS CNAME entry wouldn't make sense. Assuming the two hosts are effectively distinct, they could have their own valid certificate for `user1.theirsite.com` and make a redirection to `https://user1.theirsite.com/`. The redirection would also be visible in the address bar.

If you really wanted to have a CNAME from `user1.theirsite.com` to `user1.mysite.com`, they might be able to give you their certificate and private key so that you host it on your site too, using Server Name Indication (assuming same port, and of course same IP address since you're using a CNAME). This would work for clients that support SNI. There would however be a certain risk to them in giving you their private keys (which isn't generally recommended).

Comment: This is disappointing.  I guess I'll have to stay off https and then redirect them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The following is set up and working:

DNS entry for `a.corp.com` -> CNAME `b.corp2.com` -> A `1.2.3.4`

The haproxy at `1.2.3.4` will serve up the cert for `a.corp.com` and the site loads fine from a webserver backend.

So, on your server you will need `user1.theirsite.com` cert and it will work.